# Algorithm for finding inverse images of a local diffeomorphism

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let  $F : R^k \to R^k$ be a smooth map whose Jacobian 
$J(F): R^k \to R$ vanishes on a discrete set $S$, so that if 
$O$ is the complement of $S$, then $f: O \to R^k$, the 
restriction of $F$, is a local diffeomorphism, and in particular 
there are only finitely many points $x$  inside the unit ball of 
$R^k$ such that $f(x) = 0$. What I would like to know is if 
there any a good algorithm for finding such points $x$. 
Of course, if $k=1$ this is easy, using the Intermediate Value 
Theorem; just partition the interval $[-1,1]$ into a reasonably large
number $N$ of subintervals of length $2/N$ and test on which 
subintervals $f$ changes sign, and then use bisection to locate 
a zero in those subintervals. If $k>1$ I suspect that some sort 
of application of Marching Cubes may work, but the usual search 
methods have not turned up anything.

Comment: With a lipschitz bound on $DF$, Newton's method gives an algorithm to approximate $F^{-1}$ effectively.  There's a version of this written up in Hubbard's calculus textbook.

Comment: Do you have $F$ as "a formula", or do you only have the ability to evaluate up to some precision on a suitably dense grid in $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: @Nanda  For the application I have in mind, F will be given by a formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a Lipschitz bound on the derivative, Newton's method gives an algorithm to efficiently approximate $F^{-1}$.  [Hubbard's calculus textbook](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/vectorcalculus.html) has a write-up using this perspective, viewing the result as a consequence of Kantorovich's Theorem.  There's a fairly extensive analysis of the absolute error.

Comment: Yes!  Newton's Method is clearly the way to go. For $k=1$, the algorithm I wrote in fact did use Newton's Method, (rather than bisection) since it is much faster. But I guess I forgot that Newton's Method works in higher dimensions too.  Thanks Ryan.